# How to edit stored procedure in migration transparently?

Tags: git, laravel, migration

I have a migration in Laravel project, that creates a stored procedure in the database. It looks nice the first time I create this migration.

But if I want to change an existing stored procedure, I have to create a **new** migration, containing the new version of the procedure code.

It works, but it doesn't allow to make and see clear `diff`'s in `git`.

Here is an example migration:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GenerateReport extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement(<<<SQL
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc() RETURNS void AS
\$func\$
BEGIN
  COPY (SELECT 1) TO '/tmp/myfile.tmp' BINARY;
END
\$func\$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SQL
        );
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("DROP FUNCTION myfunc()");
    }
}
```

My question - is there a way to work with migrations and be able to see clearly every change in every line of migration in `git`?

- I dont want run `diff` tool manually for several files to see changes.
- I may just edit existing file with old migration and manually delete row in `migration` table. But it's a hack and I may forget to do it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311868/1920758) by @Denis Mysenko.

Create a file with SQL query for each migration, for example, `database/my_procedure.sql`.

After changing this file create a new minimalistic migration like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GenerateReport extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $filename = base_path() . '/database/database/my_procedure.sql';
        DB::statement(file_get_contents($filename));
    }

    public function down()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I see is - create one specific migration file for stored procedures, file name doesn't have any date in it to avoid confusion (eg. migrations/add_stored_procedures.php).

Whenever there is a need to modify a stored procedure - edit that existing file so that Git displays the modifications properly, as you wanted.

Force this particular migration to run every time migrations are executed. Two possibilities:

1. Extend and replace Laravel's Migrator class to allow unlogged migrations. This would be my preferred choice, Laravel is very flexible and allows to swap implementations easily.
2. Right in your migration, after you modified your stored procedure, run a raw DB query that marks this migration as 'fresh' in the migrations table to make Laravel believe it was never ran. This option is definitely easier.

Comment: Thanks for idea. "to allow unlogged migrations" -  what do you mean?

Comment: normally every migration, after execution, is being 'logged' - it's marked as successfully executed in a special MySQL table. You can see this line in Migrator.php in Laravel: $this->repository->log($file, $batch); So that's it - if we avoid this action for specific migrations (your migration with stored procedures) - target will be achieved :)